# compilation flag doesn't apply static linked library

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos

I'm working on Xcode project where I have a static library that is linked to another library which i compile with flag -DMODULE in "other C Flags (see images) .

[image]

[image]

However, during execution when I reach one of the static library functions, the  MODULE doesn't defined anymore, any idea why ?

Static library is linked prior to runtime, and composed from a bunch of .o files, so i would assume those are having the same treatment as any other .o file in the parent library that the flag applies to. Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler defines are applied during the conversion from source to object (`.o`). A static library is just a bunch of `.o` files glued together. If you already have a static library, you can't apply defines to it anymore. If you need to change the defines, you'll need to recompile the source rather than using a static library.

Remember that compiler defines are applied by the pre-processor. They replace part of the source code text with some other text. They're applied before the compiler even sees the code (let alone the linker).

Comment: thanks for your reply. So I guess what's I'm gonna do, Is making 2 such targets in Xcode (liblogger_module.a and liblogger.a), where the first compile with the flag and the second without the flag. Then I can choose which one to link. does it sound reasonable ?

Comment: that sounds exactly right. (Though if you have any power over liblogger, you may want to redesign to pass MODULE at runtime rather than at compile time, if that makes sense for your case.)